# Redirect in laravel package

Tags: laravel

I am trying to prepare package for 4.2 laravel, but when I use redirect in my package, first meta tag appears on the screen, then it will redirect. How can I solve the problem?

```
$provider = new PaylineProvider($config['api']);
            $request  = $provider->request($this->amount,
                                           $config['request_url'],
                                           $this->callBackUrl
            );
            if($request > 0 && is_numeric($request)) {
                DB::table(Config::get('payment::table'))->insert(
                    array(
                        'amount'      => $this->amount,
                        'provider'    => $this->provider,
                        'order_id'    => $this->orderId,
                        'authority'   => $request,
                        'description' => $this->description,
                        'updated_at'  => time(),
                        'created_at'  => time()
                    )
                );

                return Redirect::to($config['second_request_url'].$request);
            } else {
                throw new PaylineException($request, 'request');
            }
```

Comment: question mentioning "x,y,z does not work" must have code in the question, please add this or expect downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Add `illuminate/support` as a dependency of your package and then you have access to the Facades. You can import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect` at the top of your class.

Comment: There was no difference